# Decoding spoken word and understanding paraphrased subtitles

Tags: listening

There are parts where the subtitle doesn't match the speaker's words verbatim.

For example, in this [segment](https://youtu.be/rNLlLP73HP8?t=37), 中村選手 said something

> 〜気持ちになって、モチベーションは＿＿＿＿＿

The subtitle said something like

> モチベーションになる

I heard something like あらいます. I did check the dictionary, and I think there's something wrong with my hearing. What was the verb that he used? Also, is it just me or his pronunciation of モチベーション sounded like モチヴエーション?

Another part was [this one](https://youtu.be/rNLlLP73HP8?t=156) from 増田選手 where the subtitles read

> 嬉しいなという気持ち〜

But I think I heard it like this

> 嬉しいなっていう思いは＿＿＿＿

With the end sounding like はたつ＿＿＿わしたね。

Would it be possible to know what these words are? And what do you think are the reasons for replacing the words of the athletes? At first, I thought it was for brevity, but I realized that brevity would not be much of an issue for L1 users because they read Japanese fast and the sentences are not that long. Was it a matter of style (for example, 気持ち has more appeal to emotion than 思い)? Or was it because they spoke some non-標準語 variant of Japanese (which is unlikely though considering that Saitama is still part of Kanto region).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first video clip, 中村選手 said

> がんばろうという気持ちになって、モチベーションはあがります。

The verb is "あがる". "あがる" is an intransitive verb and it's similar to 'rise'.

> Also, is it just me or his pronunciation of モチベーション sounded like モチヴエーション?

"モチベーション" is correct!! He surely pronounced "モチヴエーション" in the video but he just made a bad articulation!!

We call such a bad articulation "滑舌が悪い". "滑舌" directly means 'fluent tongue'. It's a popular word especially for making fun of people who missed clear articulation. Recently some comedians has shown up focusing on their bad "滑舌" because it deserves to source of making laugh.

In the second clip, 増田選手 said

> 嬉しいなって思いは、また強くなりましたね。

The verb is "強くなる" meaning 'become strong'. "また" means 'again', 'more' or something like that. So he wanted to say like 'My happy mind is growing stronger'.

> And what do you think are the reasons for replacing the words of the athletes?

Interesting consideration!

In my opinion, the subtitle looks easier to get in first example. By abbreviating some redundant words, it enables to show bigger characters and it fits with 2 lines.

In the second example, your insight below may be right.

> for example, 気持ち has more appeal to emotion than 思い

However, '気持ち' and '思い' are very close each other in this case. It's also possible the subtitle composer just made this line casually during the daily swift working.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind response.